# JavaScript Image Swap with a Timer and Fade

Tags: javascript, image, timer, fade, swap

I have a unique situation where I am trying to take an image and swap it out after a specific time. I have that part working however I also need the pictures to fade in and out of each other and I can not figure that part out.  Please help if you can.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var picPaths = ['images/Front1.jpg','images/Front2.jpg','images/Front3.jpg'];
    var curPic = -1;
    var imgO = new Array();
    for(i=0; i < picPaths.length; i++) {
        imgO[i] = new Image();
        imgO[i].src = picPaths[i];
    }

    function swapImage() {
        curPic = (++curPic > picPaths.length-1)? 0 : curPic;
        imgCont.src = imgO[curPic].src;
        setTimeout(swapImage,5000);
    }

    window.onload=function() {
        imgCont = document.getElementById('imgBanner');
        swapImage();
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
div img id="imgBanner" src="" alt="" / /div
```

I have the correct `<>` in places on the HTML however it would not let me post the HTML into the screen.

Comment: I apologize I meant JavaScript it was a typo.

Comment: Pang, I fixed the title and tag.  Sorry.